# Forbidden: Bot was blocked by the user - laravel irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk

Tags: laravel, telegram, telegram-bot, laravel-6, telegram-api

Recently I get a lot of this exception:

`[2020-07-21 00:00:51] local.ERROR: Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user {"exception":"[object] (Telegram\\Bot\\Exceptions\\TelegramResponseException(code: 403): Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user at /home/birjande/public_html/tel.birjandelectronic.shop/packages/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/src/Exceptions/TelegramResponseException.php:58)`

in my case when a user block the botm my bot fails in a infinite loop and send a message again and again and !

I got was this kind or error, Just times 10000!

in fact if I got a error it's repeat over 1000 times !

i use **laravel 6** and **irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk**

Comment: You should catch all the possible exceptions to avoid a non-ok (200) http status code in response to Telegram.

Comment: In fact, before finding the answer of your question, you should immediately solve the vulnerability issue of your website at `http://birjandelectronic.shop/`. Your web server is not configured properly and directory listing is not disabled and even your bot token is exposed!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i create my own sendMessage like this

```
public function sendMessage($arr) {
     try {
         Telegram::sendMessage($arr);
     } catch (TelegramResponseException $e) {
         return "user has been blocked!";
     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where I need to write this to make it work?

Comment: @КостяКоростелев create a helper file and add to it , or in the main controller